# JavaScript/IE11 - Clearing DIV Contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm having a bit of an issue with IE (big surprise) and clearing DIV contents. I have a "search results" DIV that displays some items gathered via GET method (AJAX). The method itself works fine, and the data is returned to the AJAX call but the DIV in question refuses to empty itself when `document.getElementById('stupid-div').innerHTML = '';` is called, the same data is displayed in the DIV as before the AJAX call. Performing the same function in another browser works as intended and the DIV is cleared of the results once the action is taken. Any idea how I can make this work? I also tried `$('#stupid-div').empty()` to no avail.

Here is a snippet of the code.

```
<div class="Search-Area" id="Request-List"></div>
```

```js
document.getElementById('Edit-Area').style.height = '0';
$.ajax({
  url: '/SomeController/GetSomeData',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  timeout: 30000,
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
    if (!data.Success) {
      alert(data.ExitMessage);
      return;
    }

    $('#Request-List').empty(); // Does not work in IE
    document.getElementById('Request-List').innerHTML = ''; // Does not work in IE either
    alert('refreshed'); // Displays each time, so it's hitting the clear div methods

    for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById('Request-List').innerHTML += '<div onclick="LoadRequest(this.id)" class="Search-Result" id="R' + data.Data[i].RequestID + '"/><label> Request for ' + data.Data[i].Name + ' by ' + data.Data[i].User + '</label></div>';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please show your HTML. Also looks like you need to close your .ajax block.

Comment: Mixing jQuery and plain native browser API calls like `document.getElementById()` is a messy practice. That said, how sure are you that there really is an element whose id is "Request-List" - and that there's only one of them?

Comment: Open this with IE11 and check it: https://jsfiddle.net/dw92fhta/ it works. You have something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: mjw - The editor cut off the last part of the snip-it when I changed it to code so it removed the closing identifiers. I also included the HTML but it's just a DIV, nothing special.

Comment: If you only have the `.Search-Area` div, where is the `#Request-List` element?

Comment: Pointy - Can you include some reference to that? jQuery and JavaScript are the same language, just referring to DOM elements differently.. But to answer your question, yes I'm sure there is as you have to select the item to be able to perform the action that clears the DIV, otherwise the button isn't visible (clicking the item displays the button).

Comment: Also note that the `)}` at the end needs to be `})`

Comment: sjahan - That actually worked, curious that I won't work in IE on my system or another system (I tried on a test VM) but works in other browsers.

Comment: Rory - That would be the class of the DIV ("Search-Area"), the ID of the DIV is "Request-List".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  $('#Request-List').html('')

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, it was with IE and AJAX. IE cache's "GET" requests so it will not hit the same "LoadRequests" method after it is run the first time because it believes it has the data already. Switching it to a "POST" fixed this and cleared the DIV as intended.

See this helpful post for further work arounds if a POST method doesn't work for you :).

http://www.itworld.com/article/2693447/ajax-requests-not-executing-or-updating-in-internet-explorer-solution.html